# Correctly formulate Figure caption: refer the reader to the web version of the paper?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, graphics, online-publication

I have included a pretty complex map with about 10 different colors in my scientific paper in forest ecology. I am looking for a standard formule which is applied in this case, something as : ***For interpretation of the references to color in this figure caption, the reader is referred to the web version of this paper.***

However, in my caption I do not use the description i.e., *red* represent rats and *green* ~ herb, thus I do not want to start with *For interpretation of the references to colour in this figure caption...*

How can I correctly write: *please, for color representation of the figure, refer to the web version of the paper*?

I am not an English native speaker.

Could be the following formulation correct?

***The reader is referred to the web version of this paper for the color representation of this figure.***

If not, do you have some better suggestions?

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you just want to tell the reader that the colored figure is available online (in case they printed it b/w)?

If so, then the usual approach is to do the following:

> Figure 1: (Color online) This is the caption and there is some stuff here.

This may depend on your field, but [the American Physical Society (APS)](https://journals.aps.org/authors/guide-acceptable-color-online-figures-h24) recommends this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for suggestion, maybe there will be some more specific answers in forest ecology! I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

While in general I agree to the previous [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/85149/68353) by ian_itor (I have regularly used simple "(Color online)" remarks myself), be aware that some journals will require that also the b/w or grayscale print version of your paper must have fully distinguishable details in all figures.

Take for example a graph figure with three curves in red, green and blue; you would have to ensure that those colors map to distinct grayscale colors in the print.

This might be difficult to realize in a figure like yours with 10 different colors; so be prepared that you *might* have to include further distinct features like hatching to ensure proper grayscale readability.

In this case, also your description of the figure may need to be written in a way such that any reader (of the grayscale print only) will be able to fully understand all details of the figure even without access to the online colored version.

Comment: thank you for a comment, I will think about next time. This time, the manuscript (with the map with 10 colors) has been accepted for publication. Maybe this is specific for ecological topics.